# IM is a submodule of M

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

In the fisrt answer of this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430692/im-is-a-submodule-of-m) where $R$ is a ring, $I$ is a left ideal of $R$ and $M$ an $R$-module; I don't know why can't I see that $IM$ is closed under addition. If we take two elements $x$ and $y$ of $IM$ they will be in this form

$$x=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ix_i\ , y=\sum_{i=1}^{m}b_iy_i$$ where $a_i,b_i\in I$ and $x_i,y_i\in M$.

My question is why $x+y\in IM$ ?? Thank you for your time

Comment: By the way, in this problem and the other, you just launch into the question without stating what anything is. Please take some care to set up context. State $R$ is a (commutative?) ring, $I$ is an ideal, and $M$ is an $R$-module *in the question.*

Comment: I didn't want to duplicate the question, that's why I didn't re-mention the hypothesis and I referred to the link of the question.

Comment: You didn't mention the hypothesis in that question, either. (Comments are not part of the question.) Indeed, nowhere is the word ring or ideal used in either question.

Comment: Okay I apologize, I will edit it immediately. Thank you for your remarks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $i=1, \dots, n+m$ call
$$c_i = 
\left\{
\begin{matrix}
a_i & \mbox{ if }  &i \leq n \\
b_{i-n} & \mbox{ if } &i \geq n+1
\end{matrix}
\right.
$$
and analogously
$$w_i = 
\left\{
\begin{matrix}
x_i & \mbox{ if }  &i \leq n \\
y_{i-n} & \mbox{ if } &i \geq n+1
\end{matrix}
\right.$$

Then $$x+y = \sum_{i=1}^{n+m} c_iw_i \in IM$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $z_1=x_1,\dots,z_n=x_n,z_{n+1}=y_1,\dots,z_{n+m}=y_m$, and let $c_1,\dots,c_n,c_{n+1},\dots,c_{n+m}$ be defined similarly based on $a_i,b_j$. Then:$$x+y = \sum c_iz_i$$

Comment: thanks for help, it's the same idea as @Crostul's answer.